# Usage of `the` article in «The special attention» vs. «Special attention»

Tags: articles, definite-article

Question regarding the proper usage of the definite article in English.

Which of the following sentences is correct and *why*:

> *I plan to analyse the existing approaches to supply **…**, both at
>   national and international levels. **Special attention** is devoted
>   to the role of cyber activity in securing state political interests
>   Focus will be given to the current and planned projects for
>   intergovernmental cooperation….*

or

> *I plan to analyse the existing approaches to supply **…**, both at
>   national and international levels. **The special attention** is
>   devoted to the role of cyber activity in securing state political
>   interests. Focus will be given to the current and planned projects for
>   intergovernmental cooperation….*

---

And one more similar case:

> ***Among different aspects***, the %name_of_the_book% clarifies the subjects of %list_of_subjects%

or

> ***Among the different aspects***, the %name_of_the_book% clarifies the subjects of %list_of_subjects%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Special attention

is correct, because [attention](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/attention) is an uncountable noun, for which you can't use a definite article.

> Among different aspects

is correct, because *among* refers to (in the phrase itself) an undefined number of aspects.
Other context might define the group that *among* chooses from. In that case using *the* would be OK.

Comment: I agree that the version without the article is the better way to say it, but your explanation left me wondering about [all these news articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+attention+on%22&safe=active&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&tbm=nws&start=20&sa=N&biw=1280&bih=694&dpr=1.5). There are plenty of contexts where _the attention_ seems correct and natural.

Comment: I think they are trying to emphasize unique situations, but they read fine without "the". Maybe it is writing style. Anyway, the example given doesn't seem to refer to a unique situation ("existing approaches").

Comment: I agree that, time and time again, those news articles could be reworded and still read fine. However, I still have a problem with the way your answer says, "_attention_ is an uncountable noun, for which you can't use a definite article." Definite articles can indeed be used with uncountable nouns: _I hear the music; I drank the tea; she painted the furniture; he dropped the sugar; the advice was confusing; the news is dire; we could feel the energy; I saw the light_.